# Decode HTML Form Key/Value Pairs

Tags: c#

I am subscribed to a Mailchimp webhook which tells me when someone has unsubscribed from a List.

I am confused how to convert the body content I am seeing in my controller into something "useable".

The documentation says this:

> the POST request actually sends key/value pairs, just like a normal HTML Form Submission

This is what the body content looks like:

```
type=unsubscribe&
fired_at=2018-03-07+14%3A00%3A21&
data%5Baction%5D=unsub&data%5Breason%5D=manual&
data%5Bid%5D=10fe5aa79b&
data%5Bemail%5D=mickey%40mouse.com&
data%5Bemail_type%5D=html&
data%5Bip_opt%5D=2.123.194.140&
data%5Bweb_id%5D=32483953&
data%5Bmerges%5D%5BEMAIL%5D=mickey%40mouse.com&
data%5Bmerges%5D%5BFNAME%5D=Mickey&
data%5Bmerges%5D%5BLNAME%5D=Mouse&
data%5Bmerges%5D%5BBIRTHDAY%5D=&
data%5Bmerges%5D%5BDUMMY%5D=&
data%5Blist_id%5D=97406f33a6
```

The documentation says it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Stupid me! I tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode!

Comment: using HttpUtility.UrlDecode I am still seeing the "@" as "%40"

Comment: It is not a special character so the server incorrectly encode the character wrong.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references